# Printer Drivers for the Epson XP-200 for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, drivers, devices, epson

My printer is the Epson Expression XP-200, and I am unable to locate drivers for my printer. I have tried using "Add printer" to no avail. The Epson website does not list Linux drivers for this printer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I can't comment just yet, so I'll post the link here:

> http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

In the field under "Enter product name", if you type in your printer model (XP-200), then you should find a list of (four) drivers, two of which are printer drivers. (Remember to select "Linux" as the Operation System, though, or the correct drivers will not show up.)